# Enums in pch-file?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have pch-file with this code:

```
#import "ServerModel.h"

enum {
    SAVE = 1,
    REMOVE = 2,
    REMOVE_ALL = 3
};
typedef NSInteger RequestType;
```

and I'm trying to use `RequestType` in ServerModel.h but compiler doesn't know nothing about my enum. I tried to create header file for my enums and import this file in pch-file but nothing have changed.

So basic problem is: I can't use enums from .pch file in files, that are `#import`ed in this pch-file.

Is there some way to handle this problem? And is pch-file good place to put enums there?

**UPD:**

I tried to put all this enums in one header file and `#import` this file in the end of all `#import`s in pch-file and it doesn't work. 
But then I put

`#import "Enums.h" // my file with enums`

in the beginning of pch-file, before all other `#import`s and it's working.

I will be glad if somebody will explain the difference in the placement of `#import` before or after some other `#import`.

**UPD2:**

I'll try to make it more clearly:

I have `Enums.h` with enum:

```
enum {
    SAVE = 1,
    REMOVE = 2,
    REMOVE_ALL = 3
};
typedef NSInteger RequestType;
```

`MyProject-Prefix.pch` with:

```
#import "ServerModel.h"
#import "Enum.h"
```

and `ServerModel.h` with following code:

```
- (void)unlinkAccountWithRequestType:(RequestType)requestType;
```

I'm getting an error: `Expected a type` on this method. I've cleaned my project and getting same error.

When I'm switching `#import`s like this:

```
#import "Enums.h"
#import "ServerModel.h"
```

Everything is good

Comment: What are you doing ???? what do you want??

Comment: There is no difference. It's your project was not recompiled. Just clean you project

Comment: @InderKumarRathore I've tried to clean projects, but still getting same error, I've updated my question, I hope it's more clear right now.

Comment: Probably you use one of those enums `ServerModel.h`.

Comment: @11684 yeah, I'm using one of them in one method, and I know that's the reason I'm getting an error, but I can't understand, why an order of the `#imports` affect on this

Comment: Well, if the compiler tries to compile `ServerModel.h` first, it encounters that enum, doesn't know what it is and reports an error. If it compiles `Enums.h` first, it already knows what that enum in `enums.h` is, so then it can compile `ServerModel.h`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Case1 :** If you import like this

```
#import "ServerModel.h"
#import "Enums.h"
```

Then compiler will check `ServerModel.h` file before `Enums.h` when it encounters `#import "ServerModel.h"` statement. And while checking you `ServerModel.h` it finds a `token` `RequestType` and says **WTF is RequestType??** and throws error on your face.

**Case 2:** If you write this

```
#import "Enums.h"
#import "ServerModel.h"
```

Then compiler compiles `Enums.h` successfully and then compiles `ServerModel.h` and again it finds a `token` `RequestType` and says yeah I know this is a `typedef` of `NSInteger` which is defined in `Enums.h`. And finally it moves on happily.